# How do you create pre-release gems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Can't seem to find docs on it, like what the gemspec should look like, etc.

Comment: For those unfamiliar with this, a pre-release gem version is only installed when using the `--pre` option, like in `gem install rails --pre`.

Comment: Lets get this one accepted! :D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just add '.pre' to the version.

'pre' seems to be the convention but any text is fine, you just add any text characters 
to the version number and it's then considered a pre-release version.

```
gem.version = "1.0.0.pre"      # convention used by rubygems itself
gem.version = "1.0.0.beta"   
gem.version = "1.0.0.rc1"
gem.version = "1.0.0.bacon"
```

Reference:
http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#prerelease-gems

Comment: I like 'bacon'. We can't we have a convention that is also tasty?

Answer (score 15):

Any Gem whose version number contains a letter is a pre-release Gem.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there is a special way to create pre release gems. You just change your version string to something like: "2.pre" and publish the gem as usual.

Take a look at this thread: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/252914